# Lag before load custom font in my action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to use a custom font for my action bar title so here is the code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        setActionBarCustomFont();
    } 
private void setActionBarCustomFont(){
        this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        Typeface customTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");

        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.title_view, null);

        TextView actionBarTitleView = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title));
        actionBarTitleView.setText(this.getTitle());
        actionBarTitleView.setTypeface(customTypeFace);

        this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
    }
```

The problem is that there is a lag before loading my font. When I launch my application the action bar icon is loaded and the text is displayed with the default font and only after few time my custom font is loaded.

How can I avoid this lag ?

Comment: Load the customTypeFace at app start up and have it in a static variable.

Comment: I can't because `getAssets()` is a non-static method moreover the actionbar icon is hidden later and there is no need to load something to do that

Comment: Such things are usually done at the time of application initialization on start-up during which a splash screen is displayed to the user.